# "hardware drivers" don't detect my GPU (NVIDIA 520M 1GB)

Tags: gpu

Ubuntu can't detect my GPU. Jockey shows no drivers whatsoever and I can't even install the nvidia drivers through sudo apt-get install nvidia-current. That's what I get :

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.2.0-030200-generic (x86_64)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/195.36.24/build/ for more information.
dpkg: error processing nvidia-current (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-current-dev:
 nvidia-current-dev depends on nvidia-current (>= 195.36.24); however:
  Package nvidia-current is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing nvidia-current-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-glx-185:
 nvidia-glx-185 depends on nvidia-current; however:
  Package nvidia-current is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing nvidia-glx-185 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for python-gmenu ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.                                                Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/desktop.en_US.utf8.cache...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-030200-generic
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-current
 nvidia-current-dev
 nvidia-glx-185
```

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and the 3.2.0 kernel. any help ?

Comment: it says "Consult the make.log in the build directory /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/195.36.24/build/ for more information"

Comment: I don't think there is a driver for 3.2.0 in the repositories of 10.04. Any idea why you use 10.04 with 3.2???

Comment: Is this for a laptop with NVidia Optimus? You might want to see: http://askubuntu.com/a/36936/38052

Comment: Can you post the contents of ` /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/195.36.24/build/` on http://pastebin.ubuntu.com?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. This is to help with the **Ask Ubuntu Clean Up**. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've downloaded a mainline kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2-precise/. Just installing the linux-image-3.2.0-030200-generic image is suitable for many cases, but if you need to install out of kernel modules like VirtualBox or graphics drivers, you'll also need to install the kernel headers package. On the linked page, these are the [linux-headers-3.2.0-030200-generic...amd64.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2-precise/linux-headers-3.2.0-030200-generic_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_amd64.deb) and [linux-headers-3.2.0-030200...all.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2-precise/linux-headers-3.2.0-030200_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_all.deb) files.

Unless you need to test a kernel, I suggest you not to use these kernels for daily live because the modules cannot be unloaded once loaded.

Furthermore, installing a newer kernel won't make your NVIDIA Optimus card get detected, see [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)

Comment: I downloaded and installed this kernel because my wireless card won't get detected on the 2.6 kernel that comes with Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: my wireless card is intel centrino N6230 and my GPU is Nvidia GeForce GE 520m and I just need them to work. I need to either activate the wireless on the old kernel or activate the GPU on the new kernel. I am in desperate need of support. Any ideas of what might solve the problem ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to try a Live CD of the latest stable Ubuntu version (Oneiric). Try asking how to get the wireless card to work, perhaps someone has experienced the same issue before.

Comment: I tried it and the wireless card then gets installed but it doesn't show that the driver supports unity although jockey says that my driver offers full support. Any idea why this happens in oneiric? if I can get it to activate unity, i would then have no problem whatsoever. Would appreciate any suggestions.